# if-continue vs nested if

Tags: java, continue, nested-if

I'm implementing some collision detection. Over time, by continually adding extra checks as the complexity of the project has grown I've accidentally stumbled into a pattern that looks like the following:

```
for (GameObject o1 : collisionObjects) {
    for (GameObject o2 : collisionObjects) {
        if(o1 == o2){
            continue;
        }

        if(!(o1.isSolid() && o2.isSolid())){
            continue;
        }

        //several more checks

        //all of the early-out conditions are passed so do
        //do some intersection checks here

    }
}
```

Looking at the whole accumulated code later, I thought if I was to refactor this I would use nested ifs:

```
for (GameObject o1 : collisionObjects) {
    for (GameObject o2 : collisionObjects) {
        if(o1 != o2){
            if(o1.isSolid() && o2.isSolid()){
                 //all conditions are met so do collision detection
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From a readability perspective I quite like the first example, as it breaks out all of the conditions clearly, and doesn't leave me with a deep set of nested ifs.
From an efficiency perspective, the first requires more comparisons each time.

Which of these methods is better? Are there any side effects that I'm unwittingly invoking by using the first rather than the second?

Comment: I would use `if(o1 != o2 && o1.isSolid() && o2.isSolid()){` Put all checks in single line (there aren't as many) and make the code even simpler to read.

Comment: I actually have several more checks, I only put 2 as an example.This is a decent option, it could be formatted nicely over several lines

Comment: If you only have a few more checks, both are fine. If you a lot more, neither is fine.

Comment: To add on @user3437460, to circumvent it I would either add more checks in your `isSolid()` or add another "wrapping" method.

Comment: Question better suits to be posted here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This would be off-topic for Code Review as it is example/stub code. Please see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about the first requiring more checks why not negate your logic and fold the second if statement into the first? e.g.

```
if(o1 != o2 && o1.isSolid() && o2.isSolid()) {
    // extra stuff
}
```

with lazy analysis of the boolean logic the statement will fail as soon as a `false` is reached.

If you're concerned about performance though I think it's FAR more important to look into collision detection strategies. For example, Oct-trees, BSP etc.

Comment: I've got a decent hash grid strategy in place, I was looking for advice on the if-continue style. Exploiting the lazy boolean makes a lot of sense here and gets effectively the same results as the nested if (I think)

Comment: @ms813 they're both effective but this approach is more readable IMO so I would prefer ANDs over nested/next to each other with `continue` statement `if`s.

Comment: yes it should produce the same results as the nested if. If `continue` does cause any performance issues I imagine they would be so minor it isn't worth worrying about. In this case the positive effects of keeping your code clean and readable will far outweigh any negatives of using continue.

Comment: As Luiggi points out, it's a taste thing. Personally, I prefer `continue` but that's just me!

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any side effects that I'm unwittingly invoking by using the first rather than the second?

Both are fine and I don't see any significant advantage of one over the other.

But if you are serious and want to make something efficient (for example in a 3D world with tens of thousands of objects to check for collision consistently), you will be looking at tree. Particularly ***[quad-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)***. This is how games actually did their collision detection.

This is a rather large topic if you study gaming in school.